# Error when adding a cordova plugin

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I got errors when I try to add a cordova plugin to my ionic project , how can I fix that ?

I have cordova 7.0.1 and node 6.10.1

```
$ cordova plugin add https://github.com/jcjee/email-composer.git
Error: Failed to fetch plugin https://github.com/jcjee/email-composer.git 
via re          gistry.
Probably this is either a connection problem, or plugin spec is incorrect.
Check your connection and plugin name/version/URL.
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 4294963228 Error output:
npm ERR! addLocal Could not install 
C:\Users\MEDANI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-114          72-66e55b5f\git-cache-
0c87610f\2da028899216518447e10db238a14f1bef40acce
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program 
Files\\nodejs\\          node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" 
"https://github.com/jcjee/email-co          mposer.git" "--save"
npm ERR! node v6.10.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code EISDIR
npm ERR! errno -4068
npm ERR! syscall read

npm ERR! eisdir EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
npm ERR! eisdir This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! eisdir and is related to npm not being able to find a package.json 
in
npm ERR! eisdir a package you are trying to install.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Med Anis\desktop\mailtest\node_modules\npm-debug.log
```

Answer (score 3):

Since Cordova CLI 7 all the plugins need a `package.json` file and that plugin does't have it.

You can use plugman to create the package.json easily

`npm install -g plugman`

`plugman createpackagejson /path/to/your/plugin`

It will prompt you to enter the plugin information that is not available on the existing `plugin.xml`

Then you can send a PR to the plugin author so other people doesn't have to do this

Comment: There are now a couple of related **open* PRs https://github.com/VersoSolutions/CordovaClipboard/pull/27 and https://github.com/VersoSolutions/CordovaClipboard/issues/28